# How can I get data from Redis in C#?

Tags: redis

I have a problem with getting data from Redis. I want to get the object using not Id column. Can I do this in Redis? Or another case when I want to get the object using Id column, but I want to have my name of this column, not just 'Id', but I have the problem with this too.

Answer (score 3):

Redis is primarily a Name/Value store.

You can set the NAME to anything you want.  If you want to call it 'Id' you can. If you want to call it 'x-y-z' you can too and store the VALUE along with it.

Redis also supports Hashes.  If you want to get an object "using not Id column" you can store similar object types in a Hash and retrieve the entire HashSet then find the object inside the list on the client side.  This is not efficient if storing large objects or if you have many objects in a list.

Ex:

```
HMSET user:1000 username antirez password P1pp0 age 34
HGETALL user:1000
HSET user:1000 password 12345
HGETALL user:1000
```

Here is a list of datatypes Redis Supports.
https://redis.io/topics/data-types

The 2 popular libraries for using C# and Redis are:
https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis

https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis